# Storing large amounts of queryable JSON

Tags: json, database, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, nosql

I am trying to find a database solution that is capable of the following.

1. Store flat, random, JSON structures separated by a table name(random_json_table_1, random_json_table_2 for example).
2. Capable of handling a large number of insert operations(+10000/second).
3. Able to query the random json structures(SELECT * FROM random_json_table_1 WHERE JSON_SELECT('data', '$.city.busses') NOT NULL AND JSON_SELECT('data', '$.city.busStops', 'length') > 5) for example.
4. SELECT queries must run fast over gigabytes of data.

I had a look at Amazon Athena and it looks a bit promising but I am curious if there are any other solutions out there.

Comment: Can you clarify that whether or not the JSON records to go into a given table will all be of the same object structure?  If so, then Google BigQuery is a candidate .. .see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json

Comment: The structure of the table will be the same, for example... id, organisation_id, json_data but the json_data's contents will be random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider BigQuery. 
Regarding 2), there is [BigQuery streaming](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) interface.
And 4), you can play with BigQuery public data (e.g. the popular BitCoin transaction table) to see how fast BigQuery can be.

Below is sample query using BigQuery standardSQL, showing how to filter data which is stored in JSON string.

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$') AS student
FROM UNNEST([
  '{"age" : 1, "class" : {"students" : [{"name" : "Jane"}]}}',
  '{"age" : 2, "class" : {"students" : []}}',
  '{"age" : 10,"class" : {"students" : [{"name" : "John"}, {"name": "Jamie"}]}}'
  ]) AS json_text
WHERE CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_text, '$.age') AS INT64) > 5;
```

[image]

Comment: I eventually figured out how to do it, I found most examples hard to understand because they don't utilize an actual table.

Comment: If you ask question about BigQuery, it is very common that people gives you an [answer with a query based on public data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55457277/select-activity-from-a-specific-date-using-sql), or a self-contained query with data inside, like mine or [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443194/concatenate-rows-with-same-id-in-bigquery-from-same-table).

Answer (score 0):

It feels like Google's BigQuery managed database might be of value to you.  Reading [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#apirequests) we seem to find that there is a soft limit of 100,000 rows per second and the ability to insert 10,000 rows per single request.  For performing queries, BigQuery advertises itself as being able to process petabyte sized tables within acceptable limits.

Here is a link to the main page for BigQuery:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/

Comment: I think Google Bigquery lacks the requirements for JSON filtered select queries?

Comment: If we think of JSON as exclusively an encoding used to describe data for transportation then when we ingest the data into BQ, BQ will store the data in its own internal formats.  I believe that BQ can ingest JSON encoded data and the result will be tables that contain rows where each row corresponds to an input JSON document/record.  From there we can perform SQL queries to find rows that match our query.  Can you elaborate on what is missing from this story that you might need/expect?

Comment: So to give you an example SQL query.

Comment: SELECT * FROM random_json_table_1 WHERE JSON_SELECT('data', '$.city.busses') NOT NULL AND JSON_SELECT('data', '$.city.busStops', 'length') > 5

Comment: The tables structure would be like so. ID(Number), ORGANISATION_ID(Number), DATA(String / JSON). I want to filter based on what the DATA column contains.