# Concatenate rows with same id in BigQuery from same table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am running this query in google bigquery

```
SELECT rep.key.id as id, te.cmnt as comment
FROM `table` rep, UNNEST(tre) as te
WHERE u_id LIKE 'test'
ORDER BY cts DESC
```

and i am geting this

```
Id                    comment
---------------------------------
5165356444286976      HEloo
5165356444286976      TEST
5165356444286976
```

I want to merge all comments with same id, for example to look like this:

```
Id                    comment
---------------------------------
5165356444286976      HEloo, TEST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `STRING_AGG()`:

```
WITH table AS (
  SELECT 'test' u_id, STRUCT(1 AS id) AS key, [STRUCT('hey' AS cmnt)] AS tre, 3 cts
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'test', STRUCT(1), [STRUCT('you')], 2
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'test', STRUCT(1), [STRUCT(CAST(null AS STRING))], 1
)


SELECT rep.key.id as id, STRING_AGG(te.cmnt, ', ' ORDER BY cts DESC) AS comments
FROM `table` rep, UNNEST(tre) as te
WHERE u_id LIKE 'test'
GROUP BY id
```